# systemd-udev rule applied multiple times (twice in my case)

Tags: systemd, udev

I have udev rule with the following content:

```
DRIVERS=="adt7310",  RUN+="/bin/ln -s /sys//devices/platform/soc/fff00000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/temp1_input /dev/temperature_adt"
```

The problem is that this rule is applied twice and in the log appears annoying  line:

```
localhost systemd-udevd[1104]: Process '/bin/ln -s /sys//devices/platform/soc/fff00000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/temp1_input /dev/temperature_adt' failed with exit code 1.
```

I have seen a lot of similar issues over the internet and many of them still unresolved. But most of them were about PC's and quite complicated rules.
Here it is an embedded system, the link is created, nothing wrong happens but I simply don't know what to tell to QA people...

Thanks

Comment: OK then. The whole distro is running on a Cyclone V FPGA's HPS. It is output from Yocto thud (2.6.2) and the rule is written by me. systemd version is 239, Linux kernel version is 4.14.134-rt63-rt. if this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be very careful when writing rules and especially when you are taking someone else rules. Always run

> udevadm info -a /sys/...device

and read very carefully the information.
In my case the solution is

> DRIVER=="adt7310" instead of DRIVERS=="adt7310"

My apologies